# VSCode Extension Language by Firstline and File-Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on an [extension for Sigma](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humpalum.sigma).

However, i have been stumbling on the language identifier for a bit and i'm not sure if its a bug or just me not knowing how stuff works.

So Sigma is a signature  format written in yaml. In the [official repo](https://github.com/SigmaHQ/sigma) they usually also give the file extension .yml for the files.

Thus i am struggling setting the correct language contribution in my package.json.
When i just give:

```
"extensions":[".yml"]
```

All yml files, even these which are not sigma files, get the "sigma"-language.

When i use:

```
"extensions":[".yml"],
"firstLine": "^title:.*$"
```

Still, all .yml files are recognized as sigma files.

When i just use

```
"firstLine": "^title:.*$"
```

Which most of the Sigma files have as the first line, every .yml file is detected as yaml and none are set as sigma.

Am i understanding something wrong? Are these parameters "Or" or "And" combined? What would you recommend me to do here?

As far as i understand these github issues, my second and third version should be working...:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10915
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/20074
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/13782

firstLine is also used in VSCodes Example:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#language-example

Answer (score 0):

It seems, it was decided that support for this feature is not needed.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/53350

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).